# How to reset a ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a ModalPopUpExtender, on click of the cancel button it should reset the original form of the ModalPopUpExtender as it was during `Page_Load`.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASPX:**

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Modal Popup</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modalStyle
        {
            background-color: Gray;
            filter: alpha(opacity=70);
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .panelStyle
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: 180px;
            border: 2px solid Gray;
            background-color: White;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" />
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scripManager" runat="server" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modal" BackgroundCssClass="modalStyle" PopupControlID="popup" TargetControlID="btnShow" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="popup" CssClass="panelStyle">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClick="HideModal" Text="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void HideModal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    modal.Hide();
    //Execute the reset logic
}
```

Comment: when i'm doing like the above.Then the modal is hiding but again when i click on the button to show the modalpopup ,it is not showing it first time.why it is happening so?

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the `ModelPopupExtender` when we click a cancel button requires the usage of `CancelControlID` attribute in the `ModalPopupExtender` control.